# Word boundary excluding hyphen in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I like the `\b` word boundary delimiter but in my view, a `-` isn't a word delimiter. It should be part of the word.

```
# in node
> 'peter bengtsson o-peter'.replace(/\b(pete|be)/gi, 'X')
'Xr Xngtsson o-Xr'
```

I wish the output would be `Xr Xngtsson o-peter` instead.

How can I do something nearly like this but make `-` be part of the word and not a boundary?

Comment: This would be trivial if only negative lookbehinds were available in JS... `</rant>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### DIY Boundary Using Capture Group

Use a capture group to define your custom delimiter. In this case, our delimiter is either the beginning of string `^` or a space character.

```
replaced = yourString.replace(/(^| )(?:pete|be)/gi, "$1X");
```

In the replacement, `$1` inserts what was captured by the Group 1 parentheses, i.e. either an empty string if we matched the beginning of the string, or a space character.

Output:

```
Xr Xngtsson o-peter
```

**Option 2**

As @jongware suggests, my regex can be tweaked to this:

```
(^|[^-\w])(?:pete|be)
```

In the right side of the alternation, instead of matching a space character as in the original, we match a character that is not a hyphen or a word character, which is closer to the intent of "expanding the `\b` boundary" in a variety of circumstances. You still need to use Group 1 in the replacement:

```
replaced = yourString.replace(/(^|[^-\w])(?:pete|be)/gi, "$1X");
```

Comment: You can replace the space inside the space-or-start with `[^-\w]`, so it will also work for `peter ("pete") petersson`. (Not asked, but this will behave the same as the original `\b` if I'm not mistaken.)

Comment: @Jongware You're right, that's a nice option. If you post it I'll upvote.

Comment: Nah, go ahead and add it to yours. Your expression works for the OP, and it's only a small improvement.

Comment: @Jongware Added it as Option 2, with due credit to you. Thank you for suggesting this, it enriches the answer.

Comment: +1 for adding both options. Hope it works out for OP

Answer (score 1):

You could always use a workaround:

```
var r = 'peter bengtsson o-peter'.replace(/(-)?\b(?:pete|be)/gi, function($0, $1) {
    return $1 ? $0 : 'X';
});
console.log(r) //=> "Xr Xngtsson o-peter"
```